# How to check if class "is" an instance of a type given as a variable in C#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, types, superclass

I have the need to do a few checks like this:

```
if(thisInstance is ThatClass || thisInstance is ThatOtherClass)
```

I actually won't be needing to do a lot of these, so I could simply write it as it is above, but I'd still prefer doing this in a more tidy way, eg. like this:

```
Type[] arrayOfClasses = new Type[] { typeof(ThatClass), typeof(ThatOtherClass))}
if(isOfAnyType(thisInstance, arrayOfClasses))
```

But for some reason I can't get it to work. For some reason even though the string representations of

```
thisInstance.GetType()
```

and

```
typeof(ThatClass)
```

would be the same,

```
thisInstance.GetType().IsInstanceOfType(type)
```

will still always result in false.

In case it makes a difference, this is a Unity project, so if calling one further GetType() for the comparable items (eg. thisInstance.GetType().GetType()) the result is always System.MonoType, in which case the IsInstanceOfType always returns true, which of course isn't useful either.

Any ideas why the comparison fails or how to make it work? Or should I just give up and simply use the "thisInstance is ThatClass" wherever needed?

Comment: I would not consider your original code to be in any way "untidy". It seems very straightforward.  Why use reflection, when you can use an operator of the language? The better question would be "can I restructure my code so that the "is" check is unnecessary?"

Comment: Well, with just those two classes, it's not particularly untidy, but it's less easily configurable, and with more classes it would appear a bit untidy in my view.

Comment: Sure, but then the question is: why do you have a program where you have to do a lot of run-time checks of the type of a thing? Rather than try to paper over any inelegant code that results from the run-time checks, instead try to eliminate them entirely.

Comment: My reason is that I want a method to choose whether to do something based on the type of class that's calling it (+ some additional conditions).

Comment: Simply do not do that. It is an extremely bad programming practice to base behaviour of a callee upon the type of the caller. Find another way to solve your problem. It sounds like you may have a *dispatch* problem: you want one thing to happen when the alien shoots a bullet at the human and another thing to happen when the human shoots a laser at the robot, perhaps?  There are well-studied solutions to this problem. Say what your real problem is and let's solve that.

Answer (score 3):

You could use something like this. The method checks a generic object whether it is of any of the types within the array and returns a bool.

```
    public static bool IsOfAnyType<T>(T obj, Type[] types)
    {
        bool isOfAnyType = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < classes.Length; i++)
        {
            if (types[i].IsAssignableFrom (obj.GetType()))
            {
                isOfAnyType = true;
                break;
            }
        }
         return isOfAnyType;
      }
```

Comment: Why the need for generics? Everything is already derived from 'object'. Using generics seems like a lot of unnecessary overhead.

Comment: @MattRowland -  I would claim the opposite. If you would use `object object` there would be implicit boxing and unboxing, while using generics the object stays of type T. In reality I guess it would translate to the same machine code, whether you use object or not.

Comment: Thanks! With or without generics, IsAssignableFrom seems to work! The weird thing is that I thought I had already tested that, but I guess maybe I thought of things the wrong way around and had the two types to test in the wrong places. So in any case, problem solved!

Comment: @Jeffed IsAssignableFrom credits should go to Scott Chamberlain

Answer (score 1):

You can use isSubclass:

```
thisInstance.GetType().IsSubclassOf(typeof(ThatClass))
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. That won't work though when the class is of the very same type.

Answer (score 1):

To get your desired way to work you could use this method:

```
public static bool IsOfAnyType(object obj, Type[] types)
{
    return types.Any(type => type.IsInstanceOfType(obj));
}
```

If you can't use Linq you can write the method like this:

```
public static bool IsOfAnyType(object obj, Type[] types)
{
    foreach (var type in types)
    {
        if (type.IsInstanceOfType(obj))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

To test this I used this code:

```
Type[] typesToCheck = { typeof(ThatClass), typeof(ThatOtherClass) };

ThatClass input1 = new ThatClass();
ThatOtherClass input2 = new ThatOtherClass();

if (IsOfAnyType(input1, typesToCheck))
    Console.WriteLine("Hello world from " + input1.GetType());
if (IsOfAnyType(input2, typesToCheck))
    Console.WriteLine("Hello world from " + input2.GetType());
```

Comment: `obj.GetType() == type` does not have the same behavior as `is`, you need to use `type.IsAssignableFrom (obj.GetType())`

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Great suggestion, I added it to my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Cool, thanks! That Linq implementation is incredibly compact. I've used it for some integration stuff earlier, but I should really start to use it on a more common basis. What's a bit counterintuitive in my view though is what that "IsInstanceOfType" actually does. I would have assumed that "cat is instance of type animal" would be true, but "animal is instance of type cat" would be false, which is why in my example I had those vice versa in my starting post. But apparently according to the docs it's true as long as "current Type is in the inheritance hierarchy", so your suggestion works!